# What does the speed of regulation mean?

Tags: induction-motor

Let's say an induction motor speed is 1150 RPM and no load condition is 1185 RPM.
How do we find the regulation speed? What does regulation speed mean in relation to an induction motor?

Answer (score 3):

The speed of an induction motor depends on the mechanical load. The speed regulation of a motor expresses **how much** its speed varies between no-load and full load. The speed regulation is expressed in percent of full load speed.

Consider a 2-pole 50Hz motor with synchronous speed 3,000 RPM, no-load speed 2,950 RPM, and full-load speed 2,750 RPM.

$$
SR (\%)= \frac{\omega_{\textrm{no-load}}-\omega_{\textrm{full load}}}{\omega_{\textrm{full load}}} = \frac{2950-2750}{2750} = \frac{200}{2750} = 7.2 \%
$$

Further reading: http://www.most.gov.mm/techuni/media/EP02043_2.pdf